# Artikel in "York gilt als besterhaltene mittelalterliche Stadt"

Tags: grammar, article

Aus [DW - Euromaxx Sendung](http://www.dw.de/euromaxx-leben-und-kultur-in-europa-2014-11-20/e-18014575-9800):

> York gilt als besterhaltene mittelalterliche Stadt in Großbritannien.

Braucht man eigentlich hier den Artikel **eine** oder **die**, um den Satz formell korrekt zu machen? Auf Englisch würde man Folgendes halt nicht sagen:

> York is considered best-preserved medieval city in Great Britain.

Comment: Keinesfalls *eine*. Denn die besterhaltene Stadt ist die einzige. Es kann keine zwei besterhaltene Städte geben. Daher entweder kein Artikel oder *die besterhaltene Stadt*. Im letztern Fall wird das *die* bei der Aussprache vermutlich besonders betont werden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich denke, du kannst den Satz entweder mit dem bestimmten Artikel "die besterhaltene" oder ohne Artikel wie im Beispiel verwenden, das bedeutet, es gibt keine Stadt, die besser erhalten ist.

Wenn du den unbestimmten Artikel (eine) verwendest, ändert sich die Bedeutung ein wenig:

> York gilt als eine der besterhaltenen mittelalterlichen Städte...

Das würde bedeuten, York ist mit anderen ebenfalls gut erhaltenen Städten auf einer Stufe, und alle diese Städte zusammen bilden den Klub der besterhaltenen Städte.

Comment: Es geht darum, ob "eine besterhaltene", "die besterhaltene" oder einfach nur "besterhaltene" richtig ist - "eine der besterhaltenen" ist noch einen Schritt weiter.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Ich denke Alexander wollte damit ausdrücken, dass bei Verwendung des Superlativs "eine besterhaltene" nicht sinnvoll ist, da die Stadt dadurch ja bestimmt wird. Ein unbestimmter Artikel funktioniert somit nur mit der Einschränkung "eine der".

Comment: ... meine Frage gehört nicht unbedingt zum Thema, aber greift hier das viel gerühmte Phänomen des Absolutadjektivs? Spontan hätte ich jetzt nämlich tatsächlich `besterhaltenste` geschrieben.

Comment: @Phab: "Besterhalten" ist doch kein Absolutadjektiv, sondern eine Steigerung von "guterhalten"? Und was soll "besterhaltenste" sein? Ist das eine Steigerung analog gebildet, aber genau so falsch wie "öfters"?

Comment: @jarnbjo "besterhaltenste" ist wohl gar nichts, im besten Fall ein zweifacher Superlativ. Aber im allg. Sprachgebrauch hört man dieser Formulierung vermutlich öfter als "besterhaltene". Deshalb meine Nachfrage was das ist.

Comment: @Phab Bestenfalls ein Hyperlativ.

Comment: @Harald Einem/r Muttersprachler/in unterschlägt das Unterbewusstsein diese Variante vorab - das kommt in dem Text aber eben nicht heraus. Außerdem ist der Kern der Frage: **Warum** (wenn überhaupt) kann man auf einen Artikel verzichten?